# MySQL Error Code: 3 error writing file (Errcode: 28)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute a query to return the number of records (which is around 4 millions).

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col) FROM table;
```

I am getting this error: 
`mysql Error Code: 3 error writing file 'C:\Winows\temp\Myffd3.tmp' (Errcode: 28).`

What is the cause of the problem. How to fix it? I tried t search, It might seems a disk space issue ? But I have 21 GB free space in the C. Does count command fro one columns require more than this ?

**EDIT:**  : The temp file name is not permanent. Each time I execute the command, I get different name in the error message.

Comment: Well, `COUNT` by itself rarely makes such noise; but you need to count DISTINCT values... By the way, is `col` column indexed? And what's its type?

Comment: BTW, try this query: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col from table) AS c;`, does it make a difference? And, last but not the least, which version of MySQL is used?

Comment: I'm using MySQL workbench 5.2.41 & also have tried the same command with SQLyog. Both of them give the same error.

Comment: MySQL workbench is a client software; what version of MySQL server is used? And, again, is `col` column covered by index? Can you show the result of `EXPLAIN` for this query?

Comment: It is MySQl server 5.5. The column is not indexed and its type is VARCHAR.

Comment: Have I already suggested trying to build an index upon this column? )

Comment: Could you post the results of this query:

EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col) FROM table;

Comment: How big is your table?

Answer (score 2):

Check that the `mysql` process user has write access to `C:\Windows\temp`.  Generally, you don't want to be writing to `C:\Windows`... you are better off [setting the directory to somewhere else](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-create.html).

---

OK. What is the file system used on C drive?  [Perhaps you have too many files in that directory if you're using FAT16 / FAT32 ?](https://superuser.com/questions/104220/is-there-a-limit-that-a-folder-can-store-number-of-files)

Comment: It's not the point, `Errcode 28` error is specifically about space.

Comment: I'm using admin account. I have executed similar command before and there was no problems.

Comment: @JuryA Are you sure the disk isn't full? ;-)  And is it `C:\Winows` or `C:\Win_d_ows` ?

Comment: The dis has 21 GB free space. It is NTFS. It is Windows\tmp